# Misunderstanding of global variable in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the variable "a" by using a function and the global variable "df". My problem is that after running the function, "df" is also altered. I just want to calculate "a" with the function, but I want that "df" stays as it is.

```
import pandas as pd
f=[]
df = pd.DataFrame(f)
df['A']=[1]

print(df)

def fun():
    a=df
    a['A']=a['A']+1
    return a

fun()
print(df)
```

actual result:

```
   A
0  1

   A
0  2
```

expected result:

```
   A
0  1

   A
0  1
```

Comment: Note that both `df` and `a` reference the exact same object. Making changes to that object will be visible from both `df` and `a`. You likely want to make `a` a copy of `df`.

Comment: `a = df` does *not* make a copy of the value. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are assiging `a = df`. they are referencing to same thing. So when you're changing some property in `a`, the `df` also gets changed. As you do not want to change `df` inside function, just use `copy()` and work with the copy. Inside `fun()`, do:

```
a = df.copy()
```